# Applying functions with a Headless WebDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the Selenium library, I am looking to run a headless WebDriver but I get a NameError. The following code should just retrieve a site's HTML code.

```
NameError: name 'options' is not defined
```

I attempted to clear my code using several functions in hopes to run multiple scripts together.

```
#coding: utf-8
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class WebDriver:

    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()
        self.extractor()
        self.teardown_module()

    def setup(self):
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.headless = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Documents/docs/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.get('https://google.com/')
        self.driver.page_source

    def teardown_module(self):
        self.driver.quit()

page = WebDriver()
page.driver
```

Comment: I think take out the `self` in `self.options=Options(self)`. So just have `self.options=Options()`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Also, your indentation is off. You need to indent the body of each function properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Matt, I have updated the code with a `option` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Documents/docs/chromedriver', options=options)
```

should be this

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Documents/docs/chromedriver', chrome_options=self.options)
```

Comment: It gives me a `NameError: name 'options' is not defined`

Comment: E̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶. Thank you immensely for your assistance!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: No, I missed what was implied by your edit. Thank you!